# Precompiling Handlebars.js templates in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, handlebars.js, pre-compilation

Looking at the [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) documentation for precompilation.

The instructions are for OSX. Can this be done on Windows as well?

If so, when they say to "install node and npm" does "node" refer to "[node.js](http://nodejs.org/)"?

Comment: Yes, "node" refers to "node.js". Should work fine on Windows but I don't have Windows so I can't say more than "should".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Install Node.js for Windows from here: http://nodejs.org/download/.
2. Run in the command prompt:

   ```
   npm install handlebars -g
   ```

Now you can use the following syntax in the command prompt:

```
handlebars <input> -f <output>
```

,where `<input>` is an original template file name, and `<output>` is a pre-compliled template file name.

Example:

> handlebars person.hbr -f person.js

Comment: it says handlebars its not recognized as an internal or external command.. i hate windows.

Answer (score 3):

In visual studio you have 2 options:

1) using a bundle transform from System.Web.Optimization

2) using a postbuild event in visual studio (requires nodejs)

see [Gist](https://gist.github.com/3214433)

Answer (score -1):

It seems like ASP.NET Web Tools 2012.2 [has built in handlebars support](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleasedASPNETAndWebTools20122InContext.aspx) (from Scott Hanselman's blog):

> Syntax Highlighting for client side templating languages within the HTML editor like:
>
> - CoffeeScript
> - Mustache
> - **Handlebars**
> - JsRender

Comment: Syntax highlighting does not != precompiling