# How can I precompile HandlebarsJS templates from Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, handlebars.js

Is it possible to precompile Handlebars Templates from a postbuild event of Visual Studio or in the App_Start of a MVC web app?
Thanks so much in advance.
Dale

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, you have many options:

1. You can install node.js for windows and npm, and configure a post-build event to the compilation ([example here from previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938892/precompiling-handlebars-js-templates-in-windows))
2. If you're using ember.js, [here's an implementation](https://github.com/Myslik/csharp-ember-handlebars) that uses bundle transformation to achieve precompilation.
3. Another for ember.js that supports components, [here's the implementation](https://github.com/kingpin2k/HandlebarsHelper), that also uses bundle transformation.
4. Here is an [example of compilation on C#](http://ianobermiller.com/blog/2012/07/25/precompile-handlebars-template-in-net-using-jurassic/) using the Jurassic javascript compiler

Comment: Thanks ahmed - I searched and searched yesterday, and didnt find that answer (number 1 above) Thanks for pointing it out. So would I simply install node for windows, and then add the command line stuff to my post build event?

Comment: Yeah, you basically install node, try out the compile methods, and if it works fine then you can setup a batch file to run the commands after the build

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is using bundle transform and the jurrasic js compiler to generate a js file with all your compiled views and partial views in it.

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterHandlBarBundles(BundleCollection bundles, string path)
    {
        HandleBarBundleTransform transform = new HandleBarBundleTransform();
        transform.jsPath = path;
        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/views.js", transform).IncludeDirectory("~/views", "*.hbs", true));
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of not requiring node.js or ember while still using a simple bundletransform hook.

[The full source for the HandleBarBundleTransform is here](https://gist.github.com/agbell/70f06205e205cd995850).

This has the convenience of the ember solution(s) @ahmed posted for those not using ember.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was on Visual Studio 2010 but I found it when looking for a solution to Handlebars recompile in VS2013. I spent some time looking at solutions until I found that [Web Essentials for Visual Studio](http://vswebessentials.com/) added [auto-precompile of handlebars templates](https://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3738742-auto-precompile-handlebars-templates) in November 2014.

This feature in Web Essentials is not very well publicised and I only found it when I was building my solution and  found that a `.hbs.js` file automatically appeared when I edited a handlebar `.hbs` file! I wasted a lot of time looking for solutions when it was already there.

I hope this answer helps someone else.